# New domain user is created against dismounted (wrong) mail box database

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, windows-sbs

I have a dismounted mailbox database in my exchange 2010 server and my main mounted mailbox database. When I create a new domain account it creates their mailbox against the dismounted one.

How can I change the default mailbox used for new user accounts?

I am using Windows SBS 2011.

Edit: Just to note, I am using the SBS Console to add the new user.

Comment: A disconnected mailbox or a dismounted mailbox database?

Comment: A dismounted mailbox.

Comment: You cannot dismount a mailbox. So, a dismounted mailbox database?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is control provisioning by excluding one of the mailbox databases from automatic provisioning (using the Exchange Management Shell):

```
Set-MailboxDatabase –Identity ‘NotTheDefaultDatabase′ –IsExcludedFromProvisioning $True
Set-MailboxDatabase –Identity ‘TheCorrectDatabase′ –IsExcludedFromProvisioning $False
```

Comment: I ran both of those commands. When running it for the correct box (line 2) it came back with `The command completed but no setting of 'correct mailbox' have been modified.` I created a test account but it still created it against the old mailbox database. Do I need a restart for that to work?